# How to validate SSN format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation

I need to validate user input to ensure, it follows valid SSN format.

It should follow below format.

```
 XXX-XX-XXXX
```

Example: 111-11-1111

numbers only. 
Can any one please guide me, how I do validation to ensure input string follows above SSN format?

Comment: Can you tell use what SSN is? And also what does X represent? A number? An alpha character? Upper or lowercase?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: @user3711357 I hope you have a strategy for how to handle non-US users... we don't all have Social Security Numbers like that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function for validating the **SSN** number (Social Security Numbers)

```
Public Function SSNvalidate(ByVal SSN_input As String) As Boolean
    SSNvalidate = (SSN_input Like "###-##-####")
End Function
```

The function will return a **Boolean value**(`True/False`). true if the ssn is valid and false if it is not a valid. based on that you can proceed.

Good luck..